# How to call a Matlab function (compiled into a dll file) from VB

Tags: vb.net, matlab

I create a function in Matlab which has some inputs and some outputs. Then I compiled my MatLab codes into a DLL file. Now I need to call this function from visual basic. But I do not know how to do it. Because of the long length of the code, I type here a little example of Matlab code which compiled to DLL.

```
function [C,D]=main(A,B)
    C=A+B;
    D=A-B;
end
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/execute.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/apiext.pdf) (16-19)?

Comment: Yes. But I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you show your VB code please?

Comment: I don't have VB code. I want to know how I should write the VB code.